# Reducing number of levels of indentation for plural stemming code in python

Tags: python

My code works fine and it exactly does what it is suppose to do. However, it has too many levels of indentation. I wonder if anyone here has anyway to reduce number of levels of indentation.

Below is my code. The section I am mostly concerned about is the plural section.

```py
#Returns stemmed sentence

def pos(sentence):

    if sentence == " ":
        return " "

    final_sentence=''
    word_list=sentence.split(" ")   
    vowels=['a','e','i','o','u','y']
    vowelFound=False
    final_word=''

    for word in word_list:

        #Remove ownerships
        if '\'s' in word:
            final_word=word.replace('\'s',"")
        elif 's\'' in word:
            final_word=word.replace('s\'',"")
        else:
            final_word=word

        #Remove Plurals
        if final_word.endswith('s'):
            if word[-2] in vowels:
                for c in word:
                    if c in vowels:
                        vowelFound=True
                        print(vowelFound)
                        break
                if vowelFound:
                    if not word.endswith('us') or word.endswith('ss'):
                        if word.endswith('sses'):
                            final_word=word.replace("sses","ss")
                        elif word.endswith('ies'):
                            final_word=word.replace('ies','i')
                            if len(final_word)<=2:
                                final_word=word
                        elif word[-2] not in vowels:
                            final_word=word.replace('s','')
                else:
                    final_word=word
            else:
                final_word=word

        #Remove past tense
        elif word.endswith('ied'):
            final_word=word.replace("ied","i")
            if len(final_word)<=2:
                final_word=word.replace("d","")
        elif word.endswith('ed'):
            final_word=word.replace("ed","")

        #Remove adverbs
        if word.endswith('ing'):
            final_word=word.replace("ing","")
            if len(final_word)<3:
                final_word=word

        if final_word.endswith('ly'):
            final_word=final_word.replace("ly","")

        #Remove adjectives
        if final_word.endswith('er'):
            final_word=final_word.replace("er","")
        final_sentence+=final_word+" " 
  
    return final_sentence
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Too Many indentations', Are you looking to simplify your code?

Comment: Also, does it do what it's supposed to do? Once `vowelFound` is made true, it'll be true for every word in a sentence.

Comment: yeah i am lookingh to simplify my work and thanks for noticing the vowelFound error

Comment: I'm wondering why you would write `'\'s'` instead of `"'s"`.  No difference in execution, but more letters to type.

Comment: You have to break this code into functions. I tried to reduce number of nested conditions in your code but it changed a little but not noticeable. You need one function to remove ownership. One to remove plurals. One to convert past tense to present. One to remove adverbs and one to remove adj. But remember that these functions should be separate. Meaning that they should work by their own. When you have written them, just use them together in `pos` function.